# Why is there a table when I scrape with beautifulSoup, but not pandas

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

Trying to scrape entries on [this](http://www.signalpeptide.de/index.php?sess=&m=listspdb_bacteria&s=details&id=1000&listname=) page into a tab-delimited format (mainly pulling out the sequence and UniProt accession number).

When I run:

```
url = 'www.signalpeptide.de/index.php?sess=&m=listspdb_bacteria&s=details&id=1000&listname='    
table = pd.read_html(url)
print(table)
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrape_signalpeptides.py", line 7, in <module>
    table = pd.read_html(url)
  File "/Users/ION/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 1094, in read_html
    displayed_only=displayed_only)
  File "/Users/ION/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 916, in _parse
    raise_with_traceback(retained)
  File "/Users/ION/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py", line 420, in raise_with_traceback
    raise exc.with_traceback(traceback)
ValueError: No tables found
```

So then I tried the beautiful soup method:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.signalpeptide.de/index.php?sess=&m=listspdb_bacteria&s=details&id=1000&listname='
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, "lxml")
print(soup)
```

and I can see there is data there. Does anyone have an idea why can I not parse this page with pandas.read_html?
Edit 1: Based on suggestion below I ran this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
s = requests.session()
s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36'
res = s.get('https://www.signalpeptide.de/index.php?sess=&m=listspdb_bacteria&s=details&id=2&listname=')
print(res)
```

....I changed the URL to all of www,http and https; and for all I get errors relating to connection errors, e.g.

```
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x1114f0898>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused

urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.signalpeptide.de', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /index.php?sess=&m=listspdb_bacteria&s=details&id=2&listname= (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x1114f0898>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'

ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this issue. `pd.read_html('http://www.signalpeptide.de/index.php?sess=&m=listspdb_bacteria&s=details&id=1000&listname=')` returns a list of 2 dataframes, of shapes `[(42, 103), (20, 5)]`

Answer (score 1):

The `url` variable is different between your scripts.

Side by side for comparison:

```
url = 'www.signalpeptide.de/index.php?sess=&m=listspdb_bacteria&s=details&id=1000&listname=' # pandas
url = 'http://www.signalpeptide.de/index.php?sess=&m=listspdb_bacteria&s=details&id=1000&listname=' # BeautifulSoup
```

I suspect that the `http://` bit is important for pandas to recognize it as a URL as opposed to the HTML itself. After all, `pandas.read_html` interprets the argument dynamically as [described in the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html)

> A URL, a file-like object, or a raw string containing HTML. Note that lxml only accepts the http, ftp and file url protocols. If you have a URL that starts with 'https' you might try removing the 's'.

Where specifically the part *If you have a URL that starts with 'https' you might try removing the 's'* leads me to believe the `http://` is important for it to know it is a link as opposed to a "file-like object" or raw HTML.

If the error is exceeding max retries, you probably need to implement a `requests.session` with headers. A previous code I've done with this looked like:

```
import requests

s = requests.session()
s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36'

res = s.get('your_url')
```

At which point you should be able to interpret the `res` object the same way you would a normal `requests.get()` object (you can call methods like `.text` and such). I'm not too sure how the `s.headers` work, it was just from another SO post that I copied and fixed my script!

## update

Part of the error message from your last code block is

> ssl.CertificateError: hostname 'www.signalpeptide.de' doesn't match either of 'www.kg13.art', 'www.thpr.net'

Which means their SSL certificate is not valid, and `https` probably won't work because the host cannot be verified. I adjusted it to `http` and to show the resulting HTML:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
s = requests.session()
s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36'
res = s.get('http://www.signalpeptide.de/index.php?sess=&m=listspdb_bacteria&s=details&id=2&listname=')
print(res.text)
```

Results in:

```
C:\Users\rparkhurst\PycharmProjects\Workspace\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/rparkhurst/PycharmProjects/Workspace/new_workspace.py
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
 <title>Signal Peptide Database</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css">
 <link href='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundicons/3.0.0/foundation-icons.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="top-bar">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="top-bar-left">
   <div class="top-bar-title">
    <span data-responsive-toggle="responsive-menu" data-hide-for="medium">
     <span class="menu-icon dark" data-toggle></span>
    </span>
    <a href="./"><img src="img/logo.jpg" alt="logo" id="logo"></a>
   </div>
  </div>
 <div class="top-bar-right">
  <h3 class="hide-for-small">Signal Peptide Website</h3>
  <div id="responsive-menu">
   <ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
    <li><a href="./?m=myprotein">Search my Protein</a></li>
    <li><a href="./?m=searchspdb">Advanced Search</a></li>
    <li><a href="./?m=listspdb">Database Search</a></li>
    <li><a href="./?m=references">References</a></li>
    <li><a href="./?m=hints">Hints</a></li>
    <li><a href="./?m=links">Links</a></li>
    <li><a href="./?m=imprint">Imprint</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="row columns">
<div class="content">
<span class="headline">Signal Peptide Database - Bacteria</span><br><br>
<form action="index.php" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="sess" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="m" value="listspdb_bacteria">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="a" value="save">
<table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="0">
<tr>
<td colspan="3" class="tabhead">&nbsp;<b>Entry Details</b></td></tr>
<tr height="23">
<td class="highlight">ID</td>
<td class="highlight" width="50">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="highlight">2</td>
</tr>
<tr height="23">
<td class="highlight">Source Database</td>
<td class="highlight" width="50">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="highlight">UniProtKB/Swiss-Prot</td>
</tr>
<tr height="23">
<td class="highlight">UniProtKB/Swiss-Prot Accession Number</td>
<td class="highlight" width="50">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="highlight">A6X5T5&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(Created: 2009-01-20 Updated: 2009-01-20)</td>
</tr>
<tr height="23">
<td class="highlight">UniProtKB/Swiss-Prot Entry Name</td>
<td class="highlight" width="50">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="highlight"><a target="_new" class="bblack" href="http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/14KL_OCHA4">14KL_OCHA4</a></td>
</tr>
<tr height="23">
<td class="highlight">Protein Name</td>
<td class="highlight" width="50">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="highlight">Lectin-like protein BA14k</td>
</tr>
<tr height="23">
<td class="highlight">Gene</td>
<td class="highlight" width="50">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="highlight">Oant_3884</td>
</tr>
<tr height="23">
<td class="highlight">Organism Scientific</td>
<td class="highlight" width="50">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="highlight">Ochrobactrum anthropi (strain ATCC 49188 / DSM 6882 / NCTC 12168)</td>
</tr>
<tr height="23">
<td class="highlight">Organism Common</td>
<td class="highlight" width="50">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="highlight"></td>
</tr>
<tr height="23">
<td class="highlight">Lineage</td>
<td class="highlight" width="50">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="highlight">Bacteria<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;Proteobacteria<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Alphaproteobacteria<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Rhizobiales<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Brucellaceae<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Ochrobactrum<br></td>
</tr>
<tr height="23">
<td class="highlight">Protein Length [aa]</td>
<td class="highlight" width="50">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="highlight">151</td>
</tr>
<tr height="23">
<td class="highlight">Protein Mass [Da]</td>
<td class="highlight" width="50">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="highlight">17666</td>
</tr>
<tr height="23">
<td class="highlight">Features</td>
<td class="highlight" width="50">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="highlight"><table><tr><td><b>Type</b></td><td><b>Description</b></td><td><b>Status</b></td><td><b>Start</b></td><td><b>End</b></td></tr><tr><td class="w"><font color="red">signal peptide</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class="w"><font color="red"></font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class="w"><font color="red">potential</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class="w"><font color="red">1</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class="w"><font color="red">26</font></td></tr><tr><td class="w"><font color="blue">chain</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class="w"><font color="blue">Lectin-like protein BA14k</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class="w"><font color="blue"></font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class="w"><font color="blue">27</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class="w"><font color="blue">151</font></td></tr><tr><td class="w"><font color="green">transmembrane region</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class="w"><font color="green"></font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class="w"><font color="green">potential</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class="w"><font color="green">83</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class="w"><font color="green">103</font></td></tr></table></td>
</tr>
<tr height="23">
<td class="highlight">SP Length</td>
<td class="highlight" width="50">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="highlight">26</td>
</tr>
<tr valign="top">
<td class="highlight"></td><td class="highlight" width="50">&nbsp;</td><td class="highlightfixed">----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5</td></tr><tr valign="top">
<td class="highlight">Signal Peptide</td><td class="highlight" width="50">&nbsp;</td><td class="highlightfixed">MNIFKQTCVGAFAVIFGATSIAPTMA</td></tr><tr valign="top">
<td class="highlight">
Sequence</td><td class="highlight" width="50">&nbsp;</td><td class="highlightfixed"><font color="red">MNIFKQTCVGAFAVIFGATSIAPTMA</font><font color="blue">APLNLERPVINHNVEQVRDHRRPP<br>RHYNGHRPHRPGYWNGHRGYRHYRHGYRRYND</font><font color="green">GWWYPLAAFGAGAIIGGA<br>VSQ</font><font color="blue">PRPVYRAPRMSNAHVQWCYNRYKSYRSSDNTFQPYNGPRRQCYSPYS<br>R</td></tr><tr valign="top">
<td class="highlight">
Original</td><td class="highlight" width="50">&nbsp;</td><td class="highlightfixed">MNIFKQTCVGAFAVIFGATSIAPTMAAPLNLERPVINHNVEQVRDHRRPP<br>RHYNGHRPHRPGYWNGHRGYRHYRHGYRRYNDGWWYPLAAFGAGAIIGGA<br>VSQPRPVYRAPRMSNAHVQWCYNRYKSYRSSDNTFQPYNGPRRQCYSPYS<br>R</td></tr><tr valign="top">
<td class="highlight"></td><td class="highlight" width="50">&nbsp;</td><td class="highlightfixed">----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5</td></tr><tr height="23">
<td class="highlight">Hydropathies</td>
<td class="highlight" width="50">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="highlight"><a href="./hydropathy/hydropathy.php?id=2" target="_new"><img src="./hydropathy/hydropathy.php?id=2" border="0" width="600"></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" class="nohighlight">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" class="tabhead" align="center"><input class="button" type="reset" value="Back" onclick="history.back(-1);"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form></div>
<hr>
<div class="row">
 <div class="small-4 medium-3 columns"><a href="./">Home</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="./?m=imprint">Imprint</a></div>
 <div class="small-8 medium-9 columns text-right">
 &copy; 2007-2017 <a href="mailto:kapp@mpi-cbg.de">Katja Kapp</a>, Dresden &amp; <a href="http://www.thpr.net/">thpr.net e. K.</a>, Dresden, Germany, last update 2010-06-11
 </div>
</div><br><br>
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).foundation();
</script>
</body>
</html>


Process finished with exit code 0
```

So it seems this solves your issues.

Comment: Thank you, sorry I was messing around with www, http, and https for both methods to see if it would make a difference, but the pandas method didn't work with any of these prefixes.

Comment: it was strange that others couldn't reproduce my error, and I couldn't get others solutions to work.I was messing with it, got this:

    requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.signalpeptide.de', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /index.php?sess=&m=listspdb_bacteria&s=details&id=1&listname= (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x11e15ada0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))
 I've been looking up solutions, installed pyopenssl; and added 'verify=False' to one of my attempts.

Comment: So i guess the error is I'm hitting the max number of retries for visiting a URL on the page?

Comment: @Kela If that is the error, I posted a way to fix it!

Comment: Thanks so much for your suggestion, I've edited my question to show the exact code I ran based on suggestion in case I've mis-understood, but when I try the code I posted as an edit, with any of www, http, https; I get connection refused. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Kela I do not know what you mean "tried with http", since that works for me as shown in my post. If you still have an error it is probably from your internet settings, and I implore you to make a separate post if you cannot solve it! Each post should be one Q/A and this back and forth is quickly drifting away from *Why is there a table when I scrape with beautifulSoup, but not pandas* because you are describing a `requests` issue now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://www.signalpeptide.de/index.php?sess=&m=listspdb_bacteria&s=details&id=1000&listname='    
r = requests.get(url)

tabs = soup.find_all('table')
my_tab = pd.read_html(str(tabs[0]))
my_tab[0].drop(my_tab[0].columns[1], axis=1).drop(my_tab[0].index[0])
```

This should output the main table on the page beginning with 'id 1000'.

Answer (score 0):

If you find table in soup but not while parsing using read_html, the reason could be that specific table is hidden. So you can use below snap:

```
import bs4
import pandas

# open file available at file_path
with open(file_path, encoding='utf-8') as fobj:
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(fobj, 'html5lib')

# provide your table's class_name
tables = soup.find_all('table', attrs={'class': 'class_name'})


for table in tables:
    filtered_lines = list()
    data_frame = pandas.read_html(str(table), displayed_only=False)
```

Note: Option displayed_only in read_html will allow you to parse hidden tables also.