# urllib.request.urlopen connection error max URL retries reached: how to scrape website bypassing this?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib, urllib3

I am trying to scrape all of the pages on [this](http://www.signalpeptide.de/index.php?sess=&m=listspdb_bacteria&s=details&id=810&listname=) site. I wrote this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen

output = open('signalpeptide.txt', 'a')
for each_page in range(1,220000):
    if each_page%1000 == 0: #this is because of download limit
            time.sleep(5) #this is because of download limit

    url = 'http://www.signalpeptide.de/index.php?sess=&m=listspdb_bacteria&s=details&id=' + str(each_page) + '&listname='    
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    tabs = soup.find_all('table')
    pd_list = pd.read_html(str(tabs[0]))
    temp_list = []
    for i in range(22):
        temp_list.append(str(pd_list[0][2][i]).strip())

    output.write(str(temp_list[1]).strip() + '\t' + str(temp_list[3]).strip() + '\t' + str(temp_list[7]).strip() + '\t' + str(temp_list[15]).strip() + '\t')
    pd_list2 =  pd.read_html(str(tabs[1]))
    output.write(str(pd_list2[0][0][1]) + '\t' + str(pd_list2[0][2][1]) + '\n')
```

My connection is being refused for trying the URL too many times (I know this because when I run the code with requests, instead or url.request.urlopen, the error says 'Max retries exceeded with url:':

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.signalpeptide.de', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /index.php?sess=&m=listspdb_bacteria&s=details&id=1000&listname= (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x11ebc0e48>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))
```

Other methods suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56137881/why-is-there-a-table-when-i-scrape-with-beautifulsoup-but-not-pandas/56138185?noredirect=1#comment98980852_56138185) also didn't work, one of the forum users from that post suggest I make a different post for specifically this issue.

I have looked into scrapy, but I don't really understand how to make it link with the script above. Can anyone show me how to edit the above script, so that I avoid errors such as:

```
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x1114f0898>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused

urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.signalpeptide.de', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /index.php?sess=&m=listspdb_bacteria&s=details&id=2&listname= (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x1114f0898>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'

ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

I also tried using urllib3:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
#import urllib
#from urllib.request import urlopen
import urllib3

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
output = open('signalpeptide.txt', 'a')
for each_page in range(1,220000):
    if each_page%1000 == 0: #this is because of download limit
            time.sleep(5) #this is because of download limit

    url = 'http://www.signalpeptide.de/index.php?sess=&m=listspdb_bacteria&s=details&id=' + str(each_page) + '&listname='    
    page = http.request('GET',url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
```

with the error:

```
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.signalpeptide.de', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /index.php?sess=&m=listspdb_bacteria&s=details&id=1&listname= (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x11ce6f5f8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))
```

Note that I think the first time you run this script it will run, it was just when I was running it a few times while I was testing it/writing it, that now I have it written and i know it works. Then it ran for the first 400 entries and then I got the errors above, and now it won't let me run it at all.

If anyone has an idea for how to edit this script to get around the max number of URL retries, particularly be aware that I am already getting the connection refused error, I would appreciate it.

Comment: It's likely the web server is throttling your requests and/or being [DoS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack)'d by you, and/or blocking your IP address.  You might try slowing down the rate at which you make requests.

Comment: Your code appears to pause for just 5 seconds for every 1000 requests. You will probably need a much slower rate than this, try leaving a test running with `time.sleep(1)` for EVERY request to see if you still hit a problem.